# Is it possible to append shapefiles based on field values using ogr2ogr?

Tags: ogr

We have 5 "Master" shapefiles(A, B, C, D & E). Each will have different table structure. We have 100's of shapefiles which has features which has to go to A,B, C, D & E.

We have a column in all those 100's of shapefiles, like Column Name: Master & it's values are A,B,C,D,E.

Is it possible to run a query using ogr2ogr and filter out all the features with values "A" and append them to "Master table A" ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add a sql-statement as a parameter

```
ogr2ogr -append outfile.shp infile.shp-dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM shapefile WHERE column = 'A'"
```